Render an Reality Composer Pro scene on an image anchor in RealityView
I am developing a prototype of Vision Pro app and would like to render a 3D scene imported from Reality Composer Pro on an image anchor in a RealityView. But I have no luck so far to make it work and need some guidance to move on. I got the image file stored in the assets like below:

And this is my code:
import SwiftUI
import RealityKit
import RealityKitContent   

struct AnchorView : View {
    @State var imageEntity: Entity = {
        let anchorEntity = AnchorEntity(.image(group: "AR Resources",
                                                name: "reanchor"))
        return anchorEntity
    }()

    var body: some View {
        RealityView { content in
            do {
                if let scene = try? await Entity(named: "Scene",
                                                 in: realityKitContentBundle) 
                imageEntity.addChild(scene)
                content.add(imageEntity)
            } catch {
                print("Error occurs when adding content: \(error)")
            }
        }
    }
}

What I am expected is that a scene made in the Reality Composer Pro be rendered on the position of the image anchor.  And I wonder the possibility to achieve this via RealityView and RealityKit without using ARKit in a Apple Vision Pro app.

Reanchoring 3D model made in RCP in RealityView
I dare to guess (based on the fact that your image is called "reanchor") that you have already added World Anchor to the scene in Reality Composer Pro. I also assume that you have correctly set up your reference image (read the comments as well). Make sure that your model is scaled appropriately. It’s also worth mentioning that Image Anchor does not work in the visionOS simulator - you will need a real Vision Pro device. Now that we've dotted all the i's, let's move on to Reality Composer Pro.
Reality Composer Pro
In an RCP scene, assigning an anchor (whether World Anchor or Hand Anchor) to the model itself is incorrect. The anchor must be the parent object of the model, which means you need to create a group, assign the anchor to it, and then place the model in that group.

RealityView
When you print the scene's hierarchy in RealityView you'll see something like this:

Knowing the name of your anchor, you can now easily find it in the scene and change the AnchoringComponent from World to Image. Here's the code:
import SwiftUI
import RealityKit
import RealityKitContent

struct ContentView : View {
    let anchoring = AnchoringComponent(.image(group: "AR Resources",
                                               name: "reanchor"))
    var body: some View {
        RealityView { rvc in
            if let scene = try? await Entity(named: "Scene", in: rkcb) {
                print(scene)
                rvc.add(scene)

                // Check model's dimensions (in meters)
                let sphere = scene.findEntity(named: "sphere") as! ModelEntity
                print("Radius:", (sphere.model?.mesh.bounds.boundingRadius)!)
                
                // Anchoring component
                scene.findEntity(named: "Anchor")?.anchor?.anchoring = anchoring
                scene.findEntity(named: "Anchor")?.transform.scale /= 2
                scene.findEntity(named: "Anchor")?.transform.translation.z = 0.25

                print((scene.findEntity(named: "Anchor")?.anchor?.anchoring)!)
            }
        }
    }
}


P. S.
Pay attention where the Y and Z axes of your image anchor are pointing at.
